# How to insert words in 2D array with delimiters? Using BASH script

Tags: arrays, bash

In my text file I have this:

**wordA|wordC**

**wordB|wordD**

I would like to have this array:

```
   arr=(wordA|wordC wordB|wordD)
   arr[0]=(wordA wordC)
   arr[0][0]=(wordA)
   arr[0][1]=(wordC)
   arr[1]=(wordB wordD)
   arr[1][0]=(wordB)
   arr[1][1]=(wordD)
```

EDIT: If this is not possible, how can I have this array:

```
   arr1=(wordA wordB)
   arr2=(wordC wordD)
```

Comment: Bash doesn't support multi-dimensional arrays. You can fake them to some extent with associative arrays, but element access would never use multiple square brackets like in the example you give.

Comment: Thanks for the info, bro. I edited my question. Could you please check it out?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear to me. Your example array `arr1` has a single element, namely `wordA,wordB`. Do you mean `arr1=(wordA wordB)`?

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: yeah yeah. sorry. just got used to other languages. wordA and wordB are two different elements.

Comment: It *is* possible to get something that you can access with `arr[0,1]`, though.

Comment: `bash` is simply the wrong language to use if you need this kind of data structure.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned Bash does not support true 2D arrays, but this can be simulated using associative arrays.

Something like this seems to work ok in my tests:

```
a=$'a|c\nb|d'
echo "$a" && echo

declare -A array
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a arr1 <<<"$a"
#declare -p arr1
for ((i=0;i<"${#arr1[@]}";i++));do
  IFS="|" read -r -a arr2 <<<"${arr1[$i]}"
  for ((k=0;k<"${#arr2[@]}";k++));do
    array[$i,$k]="${arr2[$k]}"
  done
done
declare -p array
```

Output:

```
a|c
b|d

declare -A array='([0,0]="a" [0,1]="c" [1,0]="b" [1,1]="d" )'
```

So we have created an associative array with name "array" that can be used in the format:

```
echo "${array[1,0]}"
#Output
b
```

You can itterate through all the keys of array either with classic double for loops or simpler with

```
for key in "${!array[@]}";do
echo "$key - ${array[$key]}"
done
0,0 - a
0,1 - c
1,0 - b
1,1 - d
```

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly, but you get the idea:

```
arr=(wordA\|wordC wordB\|wordD)

echo "${arr[0]%|*}" # arr[0][0]
echo "${arr[0]#*|}" # arr[0][1]
echo "${arr[1]%|*}" # arr[1][0]
echo "${arr[1]#*|}" # arr[1][1]
```

When you read the items in from the file you probably do not have to worry about escaping the pipes, but to create the array normally I had to :)

Comment: How would you get an element that isn't the first or last element of its row?

Comment: How long is a piece of string?  Based on the available data and presented example this methodolgy can work.  In answer to your question though, you could simply use a function which has a loop to descend as far as needed prior to stripping off the other appropriate end :)